# How do I set the version of mvn to use with m2eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I'm trying to use Eclipse on an existing project where I use Maven 3.0.3. I installed m2eclipse, but it appears to be trying to build with an old version of maven.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Windows -> preferences -> Maven -> Installations and you can choose which Maven installation to use

Answer (score 1):

Go to Windows -> Preferences -> Maven -> Installations and add your external Maven installation to the list.